# How should I align one element to the right and one element to the left inside a containing element?

Tags: css

This is very common case for me:

```
<div>
 <p>Left aligned element</p>
 <img title="right aligned element" />
</div>
```

I know three ways to solve this either

```
div{
  width: 100px;
}
p{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 70px
}
img{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px
}
```

As the size of the containers perfectly match the containing block, the right content will align with the right edge.

**Con:**
My experience(don't know why) is that the pixel count differs from browser to browser. This makes the content drop down to the next row in some browsers.

```
div{
  height: 100px
}    
p{

  float: left;
}
img{
  float: right;
}
```

**Con:** The problem with this one is that I want the containing elements height to be set by the height of the p or img, whichever is taller. With the float they get `height: 0`

```
div{
  display: relative;
}
p{
  width: 70px;
}
img{
  display: aboslute;
  right: 0
}
```

**Con:** Thisone is reliant on the height of the left element, also It is more work to update get it to work on mobile devices. (typically, the contents like this tend to be placed on top of each other)

What approach do you use? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 6):

I usually do

for left element

```
 display:inline-block;
```

for right element

```
 float:right;
```

it both resets and arranges floats. If I dont have anything on left, I just create an empty element for left then float the right in same way

Answer (score 4):

You can make the div to a `display: flex` and set the image to `align-self: flex-end`.
So you don't lost the relativity.

```
div{
  display: flex;
}
p {
  width: 70px;
}
img {
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your first approach is better. Regarding the pixel difference across browsers, it's due to the white space between the tags. You can solve that by commenting out the white space like below:

HTML:

```
<div><!--
    --><p>Left aligned element</p><!--
    --><img title="right aligned element" /><!--
--></div>
```

And in css , use `font-size:0` for `container` and define `font-size` in the child elements wherever required.

CSS:

```
div{
    width: 100px;
    font-size:0
}
p{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 70px;
  font-size:12px;
}
img{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/181/

Answer (score 0):

I usually go with something like this

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div>
        <p>Left aligned element</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <img title="right aligned element" />
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
    display: table;
    width: 100px;
}
.container > div {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
}
p {
    width: 70px;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dLjh9/)

Answer (score 0):

About your inline-block solution:
You have whitespace between your `<p>` and your `<img>` (yes, newlines + tabs are also counted as whitespace), which makes the calculated size of everything inside your `<div>` bigger as 100px. (`<p>` + " " + `<div>`)

I think most people tend to use [floating](http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/), as it is easy to use and the only drawback, as you mentioned is the parent collapsing. To avoid this, [clearfixes](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/) are something you should read about.

Answer (score 0):

For me the easiest way is to give the parent element `display: flex` and `justify-content: space-between`:

```html
<div style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between;">
  <p>Left aligned element</p>
  <img title="right aligned element" />
</div>
```

This way the paragraph will go to the left and the image to the right.

Answer (score 0):

Use float

```
       .left{
 float: left;
     }
   .right{
 float: right;
     }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation or code snippet, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

For me, this works well enough:

```
.my-div-class {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```